# mosca mqtt broker on azure

Tags: azure, mqtt, broker

I am learning MQTT and would like to deploy the open source mosca broker to an azure web app running mosca without a database (don't need any QoS that involves persistence).

I have used the code from http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-mqtt/ which is a great tutorial for an on premises deployment (see below)

```
var mosca = require('mosca')

var settings = {
  port: 1883
};

//here we start mosca

var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

// fired when the mqtt server is ready

function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}

// fired when a  client is connected

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received

server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published : ', packet.payload);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic

server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic

server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client is disconnecting

server.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

// fired when a client is disconnected

server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});
```

I can get this code running on Azure web site but do not know what to setup as the address and ports for this broker in a client using MQTT - please see below

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

client = mqtt.connect([{port:1883, host:'???'}]); //what do you use here as the port and server address here instead of localhost and 1883? I tried using the URL for the web app in azure but it does not work and i do not get any error messages.

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('client connected');
  client.subscribe('presence');
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt');
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

You have to use [MQTT over Websockets](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets),
and the server address would be :

```
var client  = mqtt.connect('ws://<app-id>.azurewebsites.net');
```

and you need to activate Websockets in azure -> Web app -> Settings -> Application settings -> Web sockets.

I hope this could help.

Comment: Lakhdar, thank you. This helped a lot. I have it working now thanks to your insight. I had to follow the steps to augment a node HTTP server with MQTT-over-websocket capabilitie by calling the  Server#attachHttpServer  method as shown in the link you suggested and when doing that with the var client  = mqtt.connect('ws://<app-id>.azurewebsites.net'); suggestion you had it worked!. Thanks again

Comment: @bulho can you please share your solution? i cant make that work

Answer (score 0):

here is the broker on Azure (web app with websockets activated)

```
var mosca = require('mosca')
var http     = require('http')
  , httpServ = http.createServer();

var server = new mosca.Server();
server.on('ready', setup);

server.attachHttpServer(httpServ);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
httpServ.listen(port);

// fired when the mqtt server is ready

function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}

// fired when a  client is connected

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received

server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published: ', packet.payload.toString());
  console.log('timestamp: ',new Date().getMilliseconds());
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic

server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic

server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client is disconnecting

server.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

// fired when a client is disconnected

server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});
```

Here is an example device interacting with the broker above. For simplicity we have the device publishing and subscribing to the topic:

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('ws://your_web_app_address_here.azurewebsites.net');

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('someTopic');
  client.publish('someTopic', 'hello from my device!);
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: do i have to do anything else? i cant make that work

Answer (score 0):

I think this sounds like an issue that occurs when you forget to unsubscribe and then resubscribe to a topic.

This can happen (for example) when you have the client and server running, then shutdown the server (which results in disconnect to the client) then restarting server, which leads to reconnecting (and subscribing) by the client. Compare with this:

1. server starts -> client connects -> client subscribes.
2. server shuts down, without client unsubscribe.
3. server starts -> client connects -> client subscribes (the second time)
4. this will lead to twice/tripple/... messages.

Is that what reproduces your problem?